# Exclude lemma separator and lemma in some eledmac notes

Tags: eledmac

I typically format the critical notes in this way:

> Secundum patet, quod nullus sensus particularis
>
> 1 quod] quia *A*

But is it possible to format some notes in the following way:

> Secundum patet, quod nullus sensus particularis potest cognoscere 
>   diuersitatem inter sensibilia diuersorum sensuum
>
> 1 *post* potest: particulariter *del. A*

I have tried the following but it only leads to undesired whitespace in the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eledmac}

\newcommand{\nolemma}[2]{%
  \edtext{#1}{%
    \nolemmaseparator[b]%
    \lemma{}\Bfootnote{#2}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\crit}[2]{%
  \edtext{#1}{%
    \lemmaseparator[b]{\rbracket}%
    \Bfootnote{#2}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering

\pstart
Secundum patet, \crit{quod}{quia \emph{A}} \crit{nullus}{unus \emph{M}} sensus
particularis \nolemma{potest}{\emph{post} potest: particulariter \emph{del. A}} 
cognoscere diuersitatem inter sensibilia diuersorum sensuum
\pend

\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

This results in the following apparatus:

[image: apparatus]

So, is it possible to change the lemma separator on the go?

Comment: not the question, but putting a `~` between "del." and "A" would look better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all the `\Xfootnote` commands can have an optional argument `nosep` (p. 16 of the handbook).

So

```
\newcommand{\nolemma}[2]{%
  \edtext{#1}{%
    \lemma{}\Bfootnote[nosep]{#2}%
  }%
}
```

In any case `\nolemmaseparator[b]`  couldn't work, because `B` is not `b`.